# Laravel: override eloquent function for get results?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can override function before save :

```
public function save(array $options = [])
{
    if(isset($this->datesConvert)){
        foreach($this->datesConvert as $date){
            $this->attributes[$date] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $this->attributes[$date])->format('Y-m-d');
        }
    }
    parent::save($options);

}
```

But which method I can use for get result ? and where is documentation for this. I am looking for something like :

```
public function get()
{

    parent::get();

    if(isset($this->datesConvert)){
        foreach($this->datesConvert as $date){
            $this->attributes[$date] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->attributes[$date])->format('d/m/Y');
        }
    }

}
```

With that I can convert 10 date rows without need of 20 mutators..

Comment: Why don't you use an accessor and mutator for this?

Comment: I have 100 dates in app, this means I will need 200 mutators and it is not realy elegant...

Comment: Have you considered the Eloquent Date Mutator? You basically put all of your field names in array, specify the format of the date and Laravel takes care of them.

Comment: Eloquent Date Mutator don't fit to my needs. Write you solution if you can...

Comment: I can suggest instead of overwriting the **get** method to make a trait with a method **getCustom** for example, where you'll call the **get** method to get all of your data, modify the dates and return. Then you can use this trait in all the models it's needed.

Comment: Can you explain why date mutators don't fit your needs?

Comment: because then I will have 200 mutators and code repetition...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [Attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) fits your needs or use [Date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

> You may customize which fields are automatically mutated, and even completely disable this mutation, by overriding the $dates property of your model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
        // more dates
    ];
}
```

**EDIT**

Another way, you can override `getAttribute` method in Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;

trait DateFormatting
{
    protected function dateFields()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        if ( array_key_exists( $key, $this->dateFields() ) ) {
            return  Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $this->attributes[$key])->format('Y-m-d');
        }
        return parent::getAttribute($key);
    }
}
```

then you can use this trait in any your model, just don't forget override `dateFields` in it

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\DateFormatting;

class User extends Model
{
    use DateFormatting;

    protected function dateFields()
    {
        return [
            'finished_at',
            // other field names that you need to format
    ];
}
```

after all you can access to this fields as usual(using magic `__get()`)

```
$model->finished_at;
```

Comment: $dates only convert string to Carbon object. Laravel "Attribute casting" can't cast from one date format to another...

Comment: my input have d/m/Y format, database Y-m-d  format and this won't work you can try, $dates are just converted to carbon object. Where I can set date format for get, and for set ?

Comment: check out `setDateFormat` [method](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setDateFormat), may be it fits you.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution, My solution is :

```
public function save(array $options = [])
{
    if(isset($this->datesConvert)){
        foreach($this->datesConvert as $date){
            $this->attributes[$date] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $this->attributes[$date])->format('Y-m-d');
        }
    }

    parent::save($options);

}

public function getAttribute($key)
{
    $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

    if(isset($this->attributes[$key])){
        if(isset($this->datesConvert)  &&  in_array($key, $this->datesConvert)){
            $value = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->format('d/m/Y');
        }

    }

    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel comes with something very useful for this problem. I'm not sure what it's called, but you can modify attributes or even add new attributes like this:

```
class YourModel extends Model
{

    ...

    public function getDateAttribute()
    {

        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->attributes[$date])->format('d/m/Y');

    }

    ...

}
```

You can retrieve this attribute like:

```
$yourModel->date;
```

**Edit after comment @fico7489**

You can't ignore the fact you always have to modify things. However there are still some solutions to make it easier.

For example you can change your date column to a string and just store your date with the desired date format.

Other solution should be modifying the date through [sql](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_format.asp). `FORMAT(Now(),'YYYY-MM-DD')`.

Example in laravel would look like (not tested):

```
YourModel::select([
    '*', 
    DB::raw('
        FORMAT(yourDateColumn,'YYYY-MM-DD')
    ')
])->get();
```

Comment: I write many times I don't want 200 mutators, I want better solution.